# How do I search for a fixed date field in OpenOffice Writer?

Tags: openoffice, date, openoffice-writer

Apache OpenOffice.org writer 3.4.1.

I have a large file with many fixed date fields. (Menu: Insert/Fields/Date, and/or AutoText from such a field.)

How do I search by field value? The Find (Find & Replace) dialog doesn't seem to do it.

I can select the whole document, paste it into NotePad++, and search the plain text, but that's a very unappealing option.

A last-resort solution involving programming (OO-Basic) would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [OpenOffice user forums](http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=56874), this appears to be a missing feature (as of version 3.4.x).

It applies to all field text, like cross-reference text, too.